# Is a caste system an obligated boundary within a nikah?

Tags: nikah, hadith-interpretation, authenticity

It is narrated in: In Kitab ul-Athar:

> Imam Muhammad (RA) has reported from Umar Radiallahu Anhu saying: “I shall issue an operative order that no girl from some high and recognized family should be given in marriage to another having a lesser status.”

What is the authenticity of the following? How should it be understood?

Likewise, is such an ruling an obligation? Is it now not permissible for a guardian to accept the marriage of someone with a lower lineage to his daughter?

Answer (score 1):

Suitability of status in marriage is prescribed according to the scholars. The meaning of suitability is that a woman should be married to a man who is equal or above her own social status. The factors in which status is reckoned include piety, lineage, freedom, wealth, profession, being free of defects etc. some of these are disagreed upon, for example the Malikis do not consider lineage to be a factor.

Marrying outside of status is permissible, as long as both the woman and her guardians agree to it. Suitability is prescribed only to protect the rights of the woman and her family because they may face embarrassment when the husband is of a lower status and the marriage is less likely to be successful when the wife thinks that she is superior to the husband. They can however choose to waive their right if they wish.

Among the evidence of this is that there are cases of marriages during the time of the Prophet ﷺ which were done outside status. For example the Prophet ﷺ  married off his own daughters to the sahaba, although none equaled his status, and he advised [Fatima bint Qais](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1480a) - who belonged to the Quraish - to marry Usama bin Zaid - a freed slave who was not from the Quraish, and he married Zaid ibn Harithato Zaynab bint Jahsh etc.

**Ref:**

> فأما إذا زوجها بغير كفء برضاها جاز النكاح لأن الكفاءة حق المرأة والأولياء، فإذا اتفقت معهم على تركها جاز
>
> <sup>— [Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/21976#p1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. That being said, what should be made of the narration I cited above? Is it authentic, and if it is, how do we take it's meaning? Likewise, could you provide some citations for all of your claims? Lastly, would it be considered mustahab to deny these factors if piety supersedes them?